# Destroying cloned element (can't select first instance)

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, destroy

I am testing some generic function building and came across this problem - cannot select first cloned element using jQuery syntax. Is it due to `eventListeners` not being present in the first please? If so, how to add an eventListener to something that is not present in DOM until cloned?

```js
var cloneAndAppendCounter = 0;

function cloneAndAppend (what, target, maxClones) { 
  var id = what.attr('id');
  var clone = what.clone(true);
  var target = target;
  
  if ( cloneAndAppendCounter < maxClones ) {
    clone.attr('id', id + cloneAndAppendCounter); 
    clone.appendTo(target);
    cloneAndAppendCounter++;
  }
};

function destroyClonedElement (originalElement, when) {
  var originalElementId = originalElement.attr('id');
  var clonedElementId = originalElementId + cloneAndAppendCounter;
  var cloned = $('#' + clonedElementId);

  
  console.log('clonedElementId:', clonedElementId);
  console.log(cloned);

  if ( (cloned) && cloneAndAppendCounter > 0 ) {
    cloned.remove();
    cloneAndAppendCounter--;
    console.log('counter: ', cloneAndAppendCounter);
  };

};


$('.clone-button').click(function () {
  cloneAndAppend($('#app'), $('.container'), 4);

});


$('.destroy-button').click(function () {
  destroyClonedElement($('#app'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clone-button">clone button</button>
<button class="destroy-button">destroy button</button>
<div class="container">
  <div id="app">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is why I am not repeating id... ?

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you are setting the id on the new cloned element, you are setting it to `id + cloneAndAppendCounter`, and then you increment the counter.  So the first clone would have an id of `app0`.  But then when you click the delete button, it tries to find the cloned element with `id + cloneAndAppendCounter` which is going to try to find an element of `app1`, which does not exist.

Comment: Look into `data()` method in jQuery, this will make your tagging more solid. [jQuery Data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the problem is not in elements being bound or not bound to listeners.
The problem is in this line

```
    cloneAndAppendCounter++;
```

or more precisely in the place you had put it, because it plays dramatic role as turned out.

So the thing is tha you append an element with a specific id to target then you increase the counter. So by the time you are pushing `remove` button the counter is more than the number of appended children by one and so that is why the first click has not effect - because it goes in vain.

Here is a working script(I rearranged problematic line to the place it best fits in and besides that changed initial counters):

```js
var cloneAndAppendCounter = -1;

function cloneAndAppend (what, target, maxClones) { 
  var id = what.attr('id');
  var clone = what.clone(true);
  var target = target;
  
  if ( cloneAndAppendCounter < maxClones ) {
    cloneAndAppendCounter++;
    clone.attr('id', id + cloneAndAppendCounter); 
    clone.appendTo(target);
//    console.log('counter: ', cloneAndAppendCounter);
  }
 
};

function destroyClonedElement (originalElement, when) {
  var originalElementId = originalElement.attr('id');
  var clonedElementId = originalElementId + cloneAndAppendCounter;
  var cloned =  $('#' + clonedElementId);

  
//  console.log('clonedElementId:', clonedElementId);
//  console.log(cloned);

  if ( cloned && cloneAndAppendCounter > -1 ) {
    cloned.remove();
    cloneAndAppendCounter--;
//    console.log('counter: ', cloneAndAppendCounter);
  };

};


$('.clone-button').click(function () {
  cloneAndAppend($('#app'), $('.container'), 4);
});


$(document).on('click','.destroy-button', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  destroyClonedElement($('#app'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clone-button">clone button</button>
<button class="destroy-button">destroy button</button>
<div class="container">
  <div id="app">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, no need to have a starting point aka counter at `-1` though as it will break the `maxClones` parameter in the function `cloneAndAppend` ?

Comment: no, it was only for my own convenience as long as I am used to have arrays starting from 0 index. you can have your own and it should not break unless you forget to update this `if ( cloned && cloneAndAppendCounter > -1 )` line. Also, as someone mentioned in comments, you can use `data-` attributes to get rid of those creapy  ids  with counter concatenated.

Comment: I am not following how to use `data-` attributes. Do you mean replace variables? Or store counter in the `data-` attr?

Comment: store counter in `data-` instead of `id`, but that is just an advice

Comment: Thanks for the advice! :)